# Teclado input type number

Tags: angularjs, html5, regex

Estoy creando una app con angularjs e Ionic. Tengo unos inputs type number pero en el dispotivo android, el teclado que me presenta es con la opcion de agregar un punto (.) y no es lo que yo necesito.

He intentado :

```
if (
        ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 8, 13, 190, 189]) == -1) // digits, digits in num pad, 'back', 'enter', '.', '-'
        || (e.keyCode == 190 && $(e.target).val().indexOf(".") != -1) // not allow double dot '.'
        || (e.keyCode == 190 && $(e.target).val().length == 0) // not allow dot '.' at the begining
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Tambien

```
text = text.replace('.', '');
```

Tambien

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" ng-model="nuevo_cliente.numero_nueva_direccion" placeholder="Número">
```

Todo esto dentro del evento `keyup` sin ningun resultado. No puedo eliminar el punto del valor.

```
$(':input[type="number"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var model = $(this).attr('ng-model');
    var myRegex = /^[0-9]\d*$/;
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (
        ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 8, 13, 190, 189]) == -1) // digits, digits in num pad, 'back', 'enter', '.', '-'
        || (e.keyCode == 190 && $(e.target).val().indexOf(".") != -1) // not allow double dot '.'
        || (e.keyCode == 190 && $(e.target).val().length == 0) // not allow dot '.' at the begining
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (myRegex.test(text)) {
        console.log("fdsf");
        text = removeDiacritics(text);
        text = text.replace('_', '');
        text = text.replace('-', '');
        text = text.replace('.', '');
        text = text.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');


    }
    $scope.$apply();

});
```

Comment: Probaste con atributo `pattern="\d*"`?

Comment: Si y tampoco funciono :/

Comment: esto es para alguna versión especifica de Android?

Comment: no, deberia funcionar en casi todas. Vamos a trabajar con 1 solo modelo en especifico que es el samsung s5, el que tenemos para pruebas 5.0

Comment: ¿Intentaste suscribirte al evento `input` y hacer el replace?

Comment: has probado con `input type="tel"` ? El teclado numerico en distintos teminales puede ser bastante distinto, pero al parecer el tipo "tel" es mas restrictivo para numeros

Comment: si, tambien probe con input tel, sin embargo existe un boton que permite agregar signos, como (, ), *, y todo eso se bloquea, sin embargo hay un boton que dice N, y ese no lo puedo bloquear, no es una N propiamente tal

Comment: @MarcosGallardo como seria eso?

Comment: Seria algo asi como `$(document).on('input', 'input[type="number"]', function() { this.value = this.value.replace('.','');}`

Comment: @MarcosGallardo funciona, sin embargo si dejo solo 1 punto no lo borra, si pongo 2 borra todos los numeros y puntos. por que sera?

Comment: Si lo que deseas es hacer que el usuario elija entre un rango de numeros podrias usar `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="30" >` en vez de ingresar el numero, se implementa como un slider

Comment: No, no necesito un rango de numeros, solo que el usuario ingrese numeros de telefono, numero de direcciones, etc. pero gracias @Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta hacerlo así:

- Suscribete al evento `input`, el cual se dispara cada vez que el valor del `input` es modificado.
- Haz un `replace` del valor actual del `input` y quita los caracteres que desees.

Ejemplo: Sacar **todos** los puntos (`.`) usando un `RegExp`.

```
$(document).on('input', 'input[type="number"]', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\./g,'');
});
```

Comment: Marcos disculpa la demora, el fin de semana no trabaje en esto, hoy lo pruebo y te comento